# How to filter column by other column in odoo 12?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I try to filter an "item" column that has a many2one type based on the names that already exist in another "itemsnames" column that has a char type, I can not write the domain in the xml file, here is my xml file:

```
<record id="sale_order_line_form_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale_order.line.form.inherited</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//tree//field[@name='name']" position="after">
                    <field name="categorie"/>
                    <!--<field name="item" domain="[('item.name','=', 'name.name')]"/>-->
                    <!--<field name="item" domain="[('item.name','in',items)]"/>-->
                    <field name="item" domain="[('item.name','in',itemsnames)]"/>
                    <field name="itemsids"/>
                    <field name="itemsnames"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Here is python file:

```
class class2(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.item'
    name = fields.Char(string='item')


class class3(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.categorieitem'
    name = fields.Many2one('module.categorie', string='Categorie')
    item = fields.Many2one('module.item', string='Item')


class class4(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
    categorie = fields.Many2one('module.categorie')

    # list1=[1,2]
    # item = fields.Many2one('module.item', domain=[('id', '=', list1)])
    item = fields.Many2one('module.item')
    itemsids = fields.Char()
    itemsnames = fields.Char()

    @api.onchange('categorie')
    def _onchange_categorie(self):
        print('»»» call onchange_categorie')
        res = {}
        items_ids = []
        items_names = []
        records = self.env['module.categorieitem'].search([('name','=',self.categorie .id)])
        for record in records:
            print(record.item.name)
            items_ids.append(record.item.id)
            items_names.append(record.item.name)
        self.itemsids = items_ids
        self.itemsnames = items_names
        print('itemsnames: ',self.itemsnames)
        res['domain'] = {'item':[('id','in',items_ids)]}
        return res
```

Here is screenshot for view

[image: view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class SalesController(http.Controller):

```
@http.route('/rounds/details', type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def pos_details_json(self):
    rounds = http.request.env['sale.order.line'].search([])
    my_list = []
    for data in rounds:
        my_list.append({'Line Name': data.item.name})

    return json.dumps(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a casting problem to me.

You are declaring `itemsnames` as char,

```
class class4(models.Model):
  ...
  itemsnames = fields.Char()
```

and even if `items_names` type is list

```
items_names = []
...
items_names.append(record.item.name)
```

when you assign a `list` to a `Char` field a type conversion must happen. So, `self.itemsnames` gets a string representation of your list, not a list.

```
self.itemsnames = items_names
```

Then you use `itemsnames` as if it has an array while it doesn't

```
domain="[('item.name','in',itemsnames)]
```

May I suggest storing in `itemsnames` a JSON representation of items_names? So you can get a list again later. The Python code may look something like:

```
import simplejson as json
...
class class4(models.Model):
  ...
  def _onchange_categorie(self):
    ...
    self.itemsnames = jsons.dumps(items_names)

  @property  
  def items_names_list(self):
    return json.loads(self.itemsnames)
```

and change the domain to

```
domain="[('item.name','in',items_names_list)]
```

#### Edited to address the `Invalid field` exception:

There are more issues:

1. When using Many2one fields, the field name must end with `_id` because otherwise, Odoo will not generate the table to store the relationship on the database.
2. `item` (now `item_id`) is a field but `item.name` is not. You need to use a related field to have that info in this model (See https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields)
3. `items_names_list` has been defined as a class property so, within your class, it must be called as `self.items_names_list`

So, try something like:

```
class class4(models.Model):
  ...
  item_id = fields.Many2one('module.item', domain="[('item_name','in',self.items_names_list)]")
  item_name = fields.Char(related="item_id.name", store=False)
```

Comment: thanks you, but i get this error:  
raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))

Answer (score 0):

pyhon class:

```
class class4(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
    categorie = fields.Many2one('module.categorie')

    # list1=[1,2]
    # item = fields.Many2one('module.item', domain=[('id', '=', list1)])
    item = fields.Many2one('module.item', domain="[('item.name','in',items_names_list)]")
    itemsids = fields.Char()
    itemsnames = fields.Char()

    @api.onchange('categorie')
    def _onchange_categorie(self):
        print('»»» call onchange_categorie')
        res = {}
        items_ids = []
        items_names = []
        records = self.env['module.categorieitem'].search([('name','=',self.categorie .id)])
        for record in records:
            print(record.item.name)
            items_ids.append(record.item.id)
            items_names.append(record.item.name)
        self.itemsids = items_ids
        self.itemsnames = items_names
        print('itemsnames: ',self.itemsnames)
        # res['domain'] = {'item':[('id','in',items_ids)]}
        # @added
        res['domain'] = {'item':[('id','in',items_ids)]}

        return res

    # @added
    @property
    def items_names_list(self):
        return json.loads(self.itemsnames)
```

Comment: May I suggest using `_logger.info` or `_logger.debug` instead of `print`?